# Jewish clergy to marry inside his congregation?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage

Does the Halacha allow a single/ widow(er) member of the congregation to flirt and date with the single/ widow(er) rabbi/ cantor of the same congregation in hope of a marriage ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the comments: "flirt" means a lot of different things; there are types of "flirting" that we would not allow any upstanding Jewish man to do! But let's try and rephrase this: suppose the rabbi of Busytown is single, and takes a trip to Workville. Assuming both communities are okay with eligibly-aged singles walking up to each other and striking up a conversation at kiddush after davening, no one would object if he was visiting Workville and started chatting with a single lady in Workville. Okay, now what happens if he does the exact same thing but at his own synagogue in Busytown?

*Really* hard to say there's an absolute open-and-shut halacha against it. As DoubleAA pointed out, people used to marry whomever they could find nearby. (Not to mention none other than Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, who was a single rabbi who fell ill to typhus; the young lady who cared for him during his disease was effectively submitting her application, and they did go on to get married.)

However today, [the Rabbinical Council of America Code of Conduct](https://rabbis.org/pdfs/Code_of_Conduct_3_13_2018.pdf) is concerned about abuse of power (or even the appearance thereof), and therefore writes:

> As a function of his position, training, expertise, teaching, and halakhic authority, a rabbi has power.  The ability to recognize and use this power wisely is essential to fulfilling his obligations.  This power expresses itself in an ability to influence the thoughts and actions of others.  A rabbi must not abuse his power.  A rabbi must maintain appropriate interpersonal boundaries between himself and his congregants, and responsibly use the power and authority of the rabbinate.

> For an unmarried rabbi, romantic relationships with those with whom he serves as rabbi are subject to power imbalance and should be
> avoided.  This creates challenges for single rabbis, especially in small communities, and careful guidance the RCA Ethics Committee or of senior colleagues is necessary.

Notice the final caveat there ... "consult higher-ups." So ... please be very, very cautious.